# Yup validation message with &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, schema, yup

I'm working with yup, the code I have so far is

```
   word: yup
    .string()
    .required('word must be 5 characters.')
    .matches(fiveCharacters, 'word must be 5 characters.'),
```

This works great, but when I try to add a non breaking space between 5 and characters

```
5&nbsp;characters
```

It shows up in the DOM as above instead of being an actual non breaking space. I tried googling around for escape options but couldn't find anything. Thanks

Comment: I read somewhere that &nbsp; is not behaving like normal space. try use this unix code ```\u00a0```

Comment: @GlenK This worked! Go ahead and answer the question and i'll give you the green check. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read somewhere that `&nbsp;` is not behaving like normal space. try use this unix code `\u00a0`

Comment: you might also be able to use `\xa0`